# Changing font using a font dialog c#

Tags: c#, fonts, richtextbox

Can anyone tell me how I can change the font using a font dialog. I'm trying to get it so either the selected text changes or if no text is selected only the font after the marker gets changed (not the whole textbox).

This is what I have so far. Thanx

```
 private void menuFont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (richtextbox.SelectedText != "")
            {
                richtextbox.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
            }
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void menuFont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK & !String.IsNullOrEmpty(richtextbox.Text))
  {
      richtextbox.SelectionFont = fontDialog1.Font;
  }
  else
  {
     //  richtextbox.SelectionFont = ?
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

you may use `&&` if `fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK`is `false` and this condition alone  satisfies the use for else clause, as per [`user210118`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210118/user210118) recommendation

Comment: Probably want && instead of & in the conditional.

Comment: "&", means if first condition is false, no need to check second!

Comment: Not sure if the else is necessary, or going to do what you think it is.

Comment: && Operator

The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.

Comment: if(fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) == false, why check !String.IsNullOrEmpty(richtextbox.Text)

Comment: Exactly, that's why you use &&.  I think you have the definition of & and && backwards.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 You are right, my apologies. I had the definition of & and && backwards. Do appreciate. have made the correction

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there SelFont, SelX that apply font properties to the selected text?  Now that I think about it, maybe it's SelectedX, but the application is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SelectionFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont.aspx) property of the RichTextBox, the example will work as you need:

```
private void menuFont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        richtextbox.SelectionFont = fontDialog1.Font;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for the selected font but what about the font after the marker e.g.

"Hey There" (change the font here so everything followin this will be the new chosen font)

Answer (score 0):

To get the following text entered to be a different font, and not just the selected text, you need to add a run block to the RTB and then write into it. I implemented a toolbar for a RTB that does something like this:

```
    public static void SetFontSize(RichTextBox target, double value)
    {
        // Make sure we have a richtextbox.
        if (target == null)
            return;

        // Make sure we have a selection. Should have one even if there is no text selected.
        if (target.Selection != null)
        {
            // Check whether there is text selected or just sitting at cursor
            if (target.Selection.IsEmpty)
            {
                // Check to see if we are at the start of the textbox and nothing has been added yet
                if (target.Selection.Start.Paragraph == null)
                {
                    // Add a new paragraph object to the richtextbox with the fontsize
                    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
                    p.FontSize = value;
                    target.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Get current position of cursor
                    TextPointer curCaret = target.CaretPosition;
                    // Get the current block object that the cursor is in
                    Block curBlock = target.Document.Blocks.Where
                        (x => x.ContentStart.CompareTo(curCaret) == -1 && x.ContentEnd.CompareTo(curCaret) == 1).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (curBlock != null)
                    {
                        Paragraph curParagraph = curBlock as Paragraph;
                        // Create a new run object with the fontsize, and add it to the current block
                        Run newRun = new Run();
                        newRun.FontSize = value;
                        curParagraph.Inlines.Add(newRun);
                        // Reset the cursor into the new block. 
                        // If we don't do this, the font size will default again when you start typing.
                        target.CaretPosition = newRun.ElementStart;
                    }
                }
            }
            else // There is selected text, so change the fontsize of the selection
            {
                TextRange selectionTextRange = new TextRange(target.Selection.Start, target.Selection.End);
                selectionTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, value);
            }
        }
        // Reset the focus onto the richtextbox after selecting the font in a toolbar etc
        target.Focus();
    }
```